# How can I integrate existing MongoDB Database to generate Django Models and view in the admin site?

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb

How can I integrate existing MongoDB Database to generate Django Models and view in the admin site?

Can I use inspectdb for this?

Are there any packages for this?

How to connect Django to existing MongoDB Database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have given Django all the relevant details to connect to the database, e.g. setting up Django as if you were about to connect to a new databse to start creating models.

Give Django the following information:

- USER
- LENGINE
- NAME
- PASSWORD
- HOST
- PORT

This can be done under settings inside the DATABASE list.

the run the following command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

more information can be found -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/